# How do you download all files using Fetch and applescript?

Tags: applescript, fetch

I have the following script (modified to remove any private information).

```
-- This line is for testing.
set the clipboard to "1234567890"

set loginName to "username"
-- Password is stored in KeyChain (you need to do manually). 

-- Create Remote path
set folderNumber to the clipboard as string
set subdir1 to character 1 of folderNumber
set subdir2 to character 2 of folderNumber

set remotePath to "/files/" & subdir1 & "/" & subdir2 & "/" & folderNumber

-- Create Local path
set homeFolder to (path to home folder) as string
set localPath to homeFolder & "LOCALSTORAGE" as string
set localStorage to localPath & ":" & folderNumber & ":" as string

-- Create Local file
tell application "Finder"
    try
        make new folder at localPath with properties {name:folderNumber}
    on error e number n
        -- Do nothing.  
    end try
end tell

-- Connect to FTP
tell application "Fetch"
    activate
    set tWindow to make new transfer window at beginning with properties {hostname:"ftpServerAddress", username:loginName, initial folder:remotePath}

    tell window tWindow
        download every remote item to beginning of alias localStorage
        close window
    end tell

    quit
end tell

-- Open folder
tell application "Finder"
    open localStorage
end tell
```

When I run the script the following line fails.

```
download every remote item to beginning of alias localStorage
```

The error I get is as follows:

> error "Fetch got an error: Can’t get every remote item of window (transfer window id 232280960)." number -1728 from every remote item of window (transfer window id 232280960)

Does anyone know what the error means or how to fix it? I've tried the Fetch website without much luck. "Fetch" btw is the Fetch FTP client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check that the `remotePath` that you're generating really exists (e.g. by adding a `log` statement such as `log tWindow's remote items` and looking up in the Script Editor's event log whether it was able to get those).

If the path is correct, I think the problem is that you're using the `download` command with a reference to a list object (`every remote item...`). In the documentation, the command expects a specifier of a single item:

> **download** specifier : the remote file, remote folder, shortcut, or url to download

That's why you need to loop through the items. [The snippet below](https://gist.github.com/1852563) works perfectly for me:

```
-- my settings for testing
set theHost to "ftp.fetchsoftworks.com"
set loginName to "anonymous"
set remotePath to "/example/"
set localStorage to ((path to home folder) as text) & "LOCALSTORAGE:1234567890:"

-- Connect to FTP
tell application "Fetch"
    activate
    set tWindow to make new transfer window at beginning with properties {hostname:theHost, username:loginName, initial folder:remotePath}
    set localStorage to (localStorage as alias)
    repeat with theItem in tWindow's remote items
        try
            download theItem to localStorage
        end try
    end repeat

    close tWindow
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I also found you can record the appleScript for the "Mirror Folder" option. From that I got a command to pull everything over as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem passing a list to `download`. But there are two problems with the original code:

```
tell window tWindow
    download every remote item to beginning of alias localStorage
    close window
end tell
```

1. The `tell` block directs the enclosed commands to a generic `window` object, rather than a `transfer window`, and the generic `window` object does not contain remote items.
2. The `download` command's `to` parameter should be an alias, not an insertion location (e.g. `beginning of ...`).

This should work:

```
tell tWindow
    download every remote item to alias localStorage
    close
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Jim. That fixed another issue for me. :)